# Send data from ajax to server with get method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

This topic is not duplicate with others my problem is in get method
i have this data:

```
var things = [
   { "name": "n1" },
   { "name": "n2" }
];
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: /controller/GetList,
    data: JSON.stringify(things),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Server side:

```
public JsonResult GetList(
    List<Thing> things) => Json("OK");

public class Thing
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i call ajax with method: "POST" and get data with [FromBody] in serverside everything is ok, but if i want to call ajax with GET method **things in server side is null or empty, WHY?**

I try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ things: things })
traditional: true
```

But it does not work

My project is in Asp.net Core 3.1

Comment: You missed: `type: "POST"`

Comment: @csandreas1 I want to send data with `GET` method

Comment: So use `type: "GET"`

Comment: @csandreas1 question is that when i want to use get method i can not get data in server side

Comment: By inspecting the console, are you sure you are sending JSON? If yes, are you decoding the data into json in your backend?

Comment: Data sent from client side but I can not get it in server how can i decode it?!

Comment: try to debug. Without knowing so much we can't help. If you put `data : 'test'` and print that out in your backend, then you can see it?  Also remove contentType for this test

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid sending data (in the request body) for `GET` requests, because it could have complications. Many services, don't expect `GET` requests to have a body and, thus they just ignore it.

If it is not a lot of data you could try sending it in the query string, but I suggest just using `POST`

Comment: Is `POST` for changing data? i just want to get data from server why should i use post method?

Comment: `POST` is for sending data to the server, it is up to you what you do with that data

Comment: Both `GET` and `POST` is for sending data to server but i think `POST` is for adding or changing resources and `GET` for getting resources, am i misunderstood?

Comment: Well, in the sense that they are both http requests, yes they both send data to the server. But GET is mostly used for **fetching** resources, like html&js code, or stylesheets.

Comment: Exactly i want to fetch data and i want to say fetch data from server with this filters(data that i send to server), then it shouldn't be `GET` method?

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the method to GET:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url: /controller/GetList,
    data: JSON.stringify(things),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want to make `GET` HTTP request and pass data on JavaScript client, you can try to pass them through querystring, like below.

```
var par = "";

$.each(things, function (i,val) {
    par += "&things[" + i + "].name=" + val.name;
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/controller/GetList?" + par.substring(1, par.length),
    //data: JSON.stringify(things),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Action `GetList`

```
public JsonResult GetList([FromQuery]List<Thing> things) => Json("OK");
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Ty for your time, i want to know if i want to send string data in ajax(get) it's possible but why we can not send object in data of ajax in `GET` mode?

Comment: You can try to pass `data: { things: things }` and implement a custom model binder.

Comment: Ty i think it will work, should i implement custom binder with IModelBinder?

Comment: yes, implement a custom model binder based on your actual scenario and requirement.